# How to join overlapping circles?

Tags: c#, math, opengl, geometry, opentk

I want to visually join two circles that are overlapping so that

[image: AltText]

becomes

[image]

I already have methods for partial circles, but now I need to know how large the overlapping angle for earch circle is, and I don't know how to do that.

Anyone got an Idea?

Comment: Hmmm good one! You can find the intersection points of the circles if you know their centres and radii. From there, you should be able to figure out the overlapping segments - the smaller of the two segments on each circle created by the intersection points... does that help? I've never tried coding this but I could try some pseudocode maybe...

Comment: Do the circles have same radii?

Comment: The circles occasionally can have the same radi but generally they don't.

Comment: Generate the equations for the points using the radii and the trig functions for the start and end angles, then solve.

Comment: my idea is that filling both of them with same color as borders

Comment: Well the idea of a circle is that you can look through it and filling them would kill this feature. If you can fill them with transparency that would be solving, but I highly doubt that this is possible.

Comment: It's just http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines in reverse. You've got all the sides of the triangle, so you'll get the angles you want to know.

Comment: This question can benefit from some clarification. Make it more related to software. What do you mean by "joining" circles? Do you mean you want to represent them in a `Region` class? Define a `Path` for the edge? Draw them on a `Bitmap`? I just don't know what "joining" circles means in terms of C#. What do all the tags except "math" mean on this question?

Comment: Those tags are just that I need it for an OpenGL project I'm writing in C#.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[image]

```
Phi= ArcTan[ Sqrt[4 * R^2 - d^2] /d ]
```

HTH!

**Edit**

For two different radii:

[image]

Simplifying a little:

```
Phi= ArcTan[Sqrt[-d^4 -(R1^2 - R2^2)^2 + 2*d^2*(R1^2 + R2^2)]/(d^2 +R1^2 -R2^2)]
```

**Edit**

If you want the angle viewed from the other circle center, just exchange R1 by R2 in the last equation.

Here is a sample implementation in Mathematica:

```
f[center1_, d_, R1_, R2_] := Module[{Phi, Theta},

   Phi=  ArcTan[Sqrt[-d^4-(R1^2-R2^2)^2 + 2*d^2*(R1^2 + R2^2)]/(d^2 +R1^2 -R2^2)]

   Theta=ArcTan[Sqrt[-d^4-(R1^2-R2^2)^2 + 2*d^2*(R1^2 + R2^2)]/(d^2 -R1^2 +R2^2)]

   {Circle[{center1, 0}, R1, {2 Pi - Phi,   Phi}], 
    Circle[{d,       0}, R2, {Pi - Theta,  -Pi + Theta}]}

   ];
Graphics[f[0, 1.5, 1, 1]]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[f[0, 1.5, 1, 3/4]]
```

[image]

And...

```
ImageMultiply[
 Binarize@FillingTransform[#], 
 ImageResize[Import@
 "http://i305.photobucket.com/albums/nn235/greeneyedgirlox/blondebabybunny.jpg", 
   ImageDimensions@#]] &@
 Rasterize@Graphics[f[0, 1.5, 1, 1], Background -> Black]
```

[image]

:)

Comment: The two radii aren't necessarily the same.

Comment: Whats with D? How do I get D? Why is it floating around somewhere in the edit?

Comment: @Cobra D is the distance between circle centers

Comment: @belisarius Out of curiosity, what tool were you using to produce the graphs?

Comment: @Phrogz The first two were done with [`Geometry Expressions`](http://www.geometryexpressions.com/), and the last three with [`Mathematica`](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/). The code is also Mathematica code.

Answer (score 8):

Now this will work 100% for you even the **figure is ellipse** and **any number of figures**

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);      

        Rectangle Fig1 = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 50);  //dimensions of Fig1
        Rectangle Fig2 = new Rectangle(100, 50, 100, 50); //dimensions of Fig2
        . . .

        DrawFigure(e.Graphics, p, Fig1);   
        DrawFigure(e.Graphics, p, Fig2);
        . . .

        //remember to call  FillFigure after  drawing all figures.
        FillFigure(e.Graphics, p, Fig1); 
        FillFigure(e.Graphics, p, Fig2);
        . . .
    }
    private void DrawFigure(Graphics g, Pen p, Rectangle r)
    {
        g.DrawEllipse(p, r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height);
    }
    private void FillFigure(Graphics g, Pen p, Rectangle r)
    {
        g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), r.X + p.Width, r.Y + p.Width, r.Width - 2 * +p.Width, r.Height - 2 * +p.Width);      //Adjusting Color so that it will leave border and fill 
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for not reading the question and the comments carefully. I am working with OpenGL, NOT .net drawing.

Answer (score 5):

Don't have the time to solve it right now. But I'll give you what you need to work it out:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#The_sine.2C_cosine_and_tangent_rules

In the picture on wikipedia you see the triangle A,B,C. Let A be the center of the left circle, B the center of the right circle. And AC the radius of the left circle and BC the radius of the right circle.

[image]

Then point C would be the top intersection point. The corner in A, α, is half the angle in the left circle.The corner in b, β, half the angle in the right circle. These are the angles you need, right?

Wikipedia explains further: 'If the lengths of all three sides of any triangle are known the three angles can be calculated.'

Pseudocode:

```
a=radius_a
b=radius_b
c=b_x - a_x
alpha=arccos((b^2 + c^2 - a^2) / (2*b*c)) //from wikipedia
left_angle=2*alpha
```

Good luck :)